# Swagger Editor similar path names

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have two separate paths defined in my schema:

```yaml
/team/{id}/people/{modified}:
  get:
/team/{id}/people/{person_id}:
  delete:
```

So these are two completely separate "things" because one is a get and one is a delete, and the second parameter name doesn't make sense as something generic.  The 'get' is passing in a modified timestamp at that location and the delete is passing in an actual person identifier.

This shows up properly in Swagger UI, but the Swagger Editor is giving an error telling me that an equivalent path already exists.  It's hard to just ignore it because that scatters errors all over the file making it hard to debug real issues.

What's the solution to something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: "equivalent path already exists" despite different parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478531/swagger-equivalent-path-already-exists-despite-different-parameters)

Answer (score -1):

you should be use /team/{id}/people/delete/{person_id}:

Comment: That's redundant.  I already know it's a delete because that's the type of call.