# Can I write same path names for different methods in REST api?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, swagger

I'm writing REST APIs using [Swagger api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-express-mw). Now, I want to write methods for insert, update and delete in following way (I've seen such paths on many APIs online):

1. **POST** (for insert)

/students

2. **PUT** (for update)

/students/{studentId}

3. **DELETE** (for delete)

/students/{studentId}

Now, 1 is okay, but 2 and 3 are same paths (but have different methods). Swagger API gives me error when I write so. So is this really not allowed?

If it's not allowed, what are some best ways to define different paths without making them long and still look 'cool'?

Comment: It's allowed in node.js and there shouldn't be any conflict.. What is said in the error?

Comment: Swagger Error
Equivalent path already exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: "equivalent path already exists" despite different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478531/swagger-equivalent-path-already-exists-despite-different-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

To define different methods (GET/PUT/DELETE/etc.) for the same path, simply list these methods under this path, like so:

```yaml
paths:
  /students/{studentId}:
    # Common parameter for all methods on this path
    parameters:
      - name: studentId
        in: path
        ...

    get:
      summary: Get a student by ID
      ...

    put:
      summary: Update a student
      ...

    delete:
      summary: Delete a student
      ...
```

Comment: What did you just wrote? get put in same path? Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Oh, I never read about that. This is what I actually wanted. But is it officially allowed to write multiple methods under same path?

Comment: ^^ This is the correct (and official) way to define multiple HTTP verbs GET/PUT/DELETE/etc. for the same path. The discussion on GitHub is about a different thing (same paths but differently named path parameters, e.g. `/students/{id}` vs `/students/{username}`).

Comment: If possible, please mark post this as the correct answer. Thank you :D